# Behavior of DHCP-client

Tags: networking, dhcp, standards

This is a question about the Internet protocol standards.

- The DCHP-client (dhcpcd-5.2.10 from Android 4.x) initializes an interface
- The DHCP-client sends a DHCPDISCOVER message
- DHCP-server sends a DHCPOFFER message
- Then the client sends a DHCPREQUEST message that contains a "Requested IP address" other than "Your IP address" from DHCPOFFER and does not contain "DHCP Server Identifer".

I see it from [packet capture](http://rghost.ru/51018352) (can be opened with Wireshark) on dhcp-server device.

RFC 2131 says:

```
The client broadcasts a DHCPREQUEST message that MUST include 
the 'server identifier' option to indicate which server 
it has selected, and that MAY include other options specifying 
desired configuration values.  
The 'requested IP address' option MUST be set to the value
of 'yiaddr' in the DHCPOFFER message from the server.
```

Question: is correct behavior of the DHCP-client? May standards have changed?

Comment: Are you sure you're not monitoring a `RENEW DHCPREQUEST`? According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565095/how-client-unicasts-a-renew-dhcp-request-if-server-id-must-not-be-filled-in) the server id **MUST NOT** be filled in during a `RENEW`-request. And seeing as the **destination** of your `DHCPREQUEST` is **unicast** (0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255) it might be a `RENEW DHCPREQUEST`. (PS. not an expert here :)

Comment: @Rik 255.255.255.255 is a broadcast address.

Comment: Mmmm, yeah... and `This DHCPREQUEST message is broadcast and relayed through DHCP/BOOTP relay agents.`. Mmm, so, we need another method to see if this is a `RENEW` or not. (I need to do some reading up on this :) But as i read it there are some cases where `'server identifier' MUST NOT be filled in`.

Comment: (again... not an expert) but am i right in seeing the last 2 `DHCPREQUEST`s do have the "DHCP Server Identifer" set (line 73 and 77)? Also reading through the [RFC 2131](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2131.html) only during SELECTING state, the "DHCP Server Identifer" must be filled in. During INIT-REBOOT, RENEWAL and REBINDING it MUST NOT be set.

Comment: Client has started a full initialization procedure after first DHCPREQUEST because server has sent DHCPNAK. It's not INIT-REBOOT, RENEWAL, etc, I think. Also there (at log) are several dhcp-clients.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to an answer... (more room ;)

First a question. Are you experiencing a delay in getting a correct IP from the server? As i see it, it took more than a minute and a half to get a correct IP (192.168.1.33). If that's the case maybe we should look closer to the requests.

---

I think the protocol is correct the way it is now.

I filtered only traffic from/to LenovoMo to/from MS-NLB-PhysServer. (At least i think i did ;)
i used filter
`((((eth) && !(bootp.hw.mac_addr == 00:bb:3a:89:67:be)) && !(bootp.hw.mac_addr == b4:98:42:d6:63:c1)) && !(bootp.hw.mac_addr == e0:69:95:74:b2:43)) && !(bootp.hw.mac_addr == 78:e4:00:9d:fd:6b)`

This is what i got (right click and choose "open in new tab" for a bigger version):

[image]

- Looking at the first DHCP Request (line #1) your client requests **192.168.1.35**.

[image]

- It gets a DHCP NAK (no correct IP) back from the server.
- The client goes in DHCP Discover mode and sends several packets for discovery (as it should).
- The server sends a DHCP Offer (also multiple times) and i think it's offering 192.168.1.33.

[image]

- At line 9 the clients **tries again to get 192.168.1.35** with a DHCP Request
  (twice, why? maybe it's stubborn ;) (it is allowed for the client to send multiple requests)
- Again server responds with DHCP NAK.
- ...
- This goes on for minute.
- ...
- Finally at line #63 the client does a DHCP Request with **IP 192.168.1.33**
  **with the "Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier"** (as it should). (see below)

I'm not sure (yet) why it takes so long but all the DHCP Requests the client makes (until line #63) are **requesting 192.168.1.35** and thus are requests for <strike>**RENEWAL**</strike> the same IP during **INIT-REBOOT**.

---

> Question: is correct behavior of the DHCP-client? May standards have changed?

But... I think the answer to the question is...
**YES**, this is correct behavior of the client
and **NO**, the standards haven't changed ;)

---

[image]

Comment: It's not RENEW, I think. 1 - RENEW is unicast. 2 - RENEW MUST NOT contain Requested IP Address. First message is INIT-REBOOT DHCPREQUEST, I think, and this packet is correct then. But I don't know about other. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @someuser Haaa, Yes... the log begins with the protocol [4.4.2 Initialization with known network address](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2131.html#section-4.4.2). That states: `The client begins in INIT-REBOOT` ... `The client MUST insert its known network address as a 'requested IP address'` AND **`The client MUST NOT include a 'server identifier' in the DHCPREQUEST message`**.

Comment: There are 3 "Transaction ID's" which begin with the DHCPREQUEST. Then the final (line #63) must be the SELECTING (where chosen IP and "server id" are a MUST). It is allowed for the client to send multiple request in one minute to make sure the server gets them. So those in between are likely re-sends.

Comment: I found a good [article](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DHCPGeneralOperationandClientFiniteStateMachine.htm). :)

Comment: @someuser Yeah, that's much easier reading than the dry material at [RFC 2131](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2131.html) ;) I'm still puzzled though as to why the Android tries the DHCPREQUEST 2 extra times (line #9 and #35 with "seconds elapsed: 1") with the old IP (for a whole minute) before accepting the OFFER of the server. You would think after receiving the first NAK it would know to accept the next OFFER. (would save a lot of time) Aah, well... it's always better than the situation described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33590).

Comment: There is another strange moment. I saw a delay between packets some hours ago. The client sends a DISCOVER, the server responds. The client sends DISCOVER again after _4-10_ (differently) seconds. I have a suspicion about the existence of some network problem.

Comment: @someuser If this is only with the Android device it could be OS specific. During my searches i found quite a lot of bugs in the DHCP implementation in Android. Like [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12066) (directly starting in the SELECTING phase with a wrong IP) and a few others too. So you might want to filter the logs in Wireshark with only traffic from another client (and server) and see if it is also abnormal. (Or [here](http://cafbit.com/entry/rapid_dhcp_or_how_do) another example of some Android traffic with double request, but within 11 seconds)

Comment: Only a few Android devices. :) But these devices are normally get address by DHCP in the home network (as their owners says). It's strange.

Comment: @someuser So you do have some troubles with the Android devices? What protocol of WiFi are you using. If it is 802.11n you might want to switch back to 802.11g. For example if you only get a link-speed of 65Mbps. Some routers have an old implementation of 802.11n and in that case i have experienced setting it to 802.11g/only would stabilize a lot of things.

Comment: I don't know about the WiFi version (need to specify) but I'll try to offer this way for solving. Thanks.